# Why React routing not working in component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working on a React web application using React router.
In my App.js file i have imported header and home component.
In home component i have 2 components called Onlinebanks and Creditcard that i imported from online-banks.js and creditcard.js files.

When the user clicks link buttons in home.js component, the Onlinebanks and Creditcard components should render.

Instead i am getting an error called Error: Invariant failed: You should not use < Link> outside a < Router>.

Why it's not working?

**INDEX.JS**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**APP.JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header';
import Home from './components/home';

class Routes extends Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {

      };

    }

    render(){

        return (
          <div className="wrapper">
              <Header/>
              <Home/>
          </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Routes;
```

**HOME.JS**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Onlinebanks from './online-banks';
import Creditcard from './creditcard';


const Home = (props) => {


   return (
    <div className="section">
            <div className="main-page">

                <div className="tab-container">

                        <div className="tab-btns">
                        <Link to="/">
                            <div className="online-bank-btn">
                                Online pangad
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to="/creditcard">       
                            <div className="creditcard-btn">
                                Krediitkaart
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                        </div>

                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" exact component={Onlinebanks}/>
                            <Route path="/creditcard" exact component={Creditcard}/>
                        </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>              
    </div>


   )
}


export default Home;
```

**ONLINE-BANKS.JS**

```
import React from 'react';


const Onlinebanks = (props) => {
   return (
    <div className="banks-container">


    <input type="button" value="Pay" className="pay-btn" id="online-banks-pay"></input>
    </div>
   )
}


export default Onlinebanks;
```

**CREDITCARD.JS**

```
import React from 'react';


const Creditcard = (props) => {
   return (
    <div className="Creditcard-container">


    <input type="button" value="Pay" className="pay-btn" id="creditcard-pay"></input>
    </div>
   )
}


export default Creditcard;
```

Comment: The error plainly says that `<Link>` will not work until you set up your `<Router>`. You may want to follow their [quick start guide](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) to get more familiar with the library. In the meantime, if you are just trying to link to a different page, just use the native HTML `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your code where you imported BrowserRouter from react-router-dom which should wrap all the other components rendered by your top level componet (app.js) or entirely wrap the app component. so, first `import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"` in index.js, then wrap App component with Router as follows

```
ReactDOM.render(<Router> <App />  </Router>,  document.getElementById("root"));
```

alternatively you can wrap the retun statment in app.js with Router as follows after importing BrowserRouter as Router

```
return (
        <Router>
         <div className="wrapper">
          <Header/>
          <Home/>
         </div>
       </Router>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Router>` is an HOC component, so you need to use it at the top most level possible. Suggestion would be to create a separate `Router` component and use it within `App.js` file above `div` tag

```js
<CustomRouter>
 <div className="wrapper">
              <Header/>
              <Home/>
 </div>
</CustomRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to better understand how react-router-dom works.

visit here for complete routing guide [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start.)

i found some major missings in your app.js file.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

<Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
```

i don't see this method in your app.js .